# programming GSM modem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, gsm, modem

I have a usb gsm modem of type lightWave. I found this code in c# that can receive, send, delete and read sms message from this modem but when a new message arrives to modem, the event that should be raised when new message is received does not get raised. I don't know what the problem is; however, I can read this message from sim after received, but I want the event of received message raised when message arrive this part of code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int port = GsmCommMain.DefaultPortNumber;
    int baudRate = 9600; // We Set 9600 as our Default Baud Rate
    int timeout = GsmCommMain.DefaultTimeout;

    dlg = new frmConnection();

    dlg.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    dlg.SetData(port, baudRate, timeout);
    if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        dlg.GetData(out port, out baudRate, out timeout);
        CommSetting.Comm_Port = port;
        CommSetting.Comm_BaudRate = baudRate;
        CommSetting.Comm_TimeOut = timeout;
    }
    else
    {
        Close();
        return;
    }
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    CommSetting.comm = new GsmCommMain(port, baudRate, timeout);
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    CommSetting.comm.PhoneConnected += new EventHandler(comm_PhoneConnected);
    CommSetting.comm.MessageReceived += new MessageReceivedEventHandler(comm_MessageReceived);
    //....
}
```

This event does not get raised when message

```
CommSetting.comm.MessageReceived += new MessageReceivedEventHandler(comm_MessageReceived);
```

This code in C# I founded at [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx)  can any help me please?

Comment: If you don't set the Handshake property then you have to set the hardware handshake signals yourself.  Set the RtsEnable and DtrEnable properties to true.

Comment: Instead of using GSMcomm you must put your own handler to receive the data and take decisions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

+CMTI

A GSM/GPRS modem or mobile phone uses +CMTI to notify the computer / PC that a new SMS message has been received and the memory location where it is stored.

keep on run the thread at event handle  `DataReceivedHandler`,

```
if(indata.Contains("+CMTI"))//Alert for message recived read message from the loacation
```

Get  the loaction and read the message from that specfic sim location.

ref http://www.developershome.com/sms/resultCodes3.asp

ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to make sure that your port, baudRate and time out is valid. And then check comm is properly initialized.

to add handler write the following code only......

```
comm.MessageReceived += comm_MessageReceived;
```

and initialize  comm by following code.......

```
comm = new GsmCommMain(port, baudRate, timeout);
```